# Testing for Collinearity in a Dataset with Categorical and Continuous Variables

Tags: r, multicollinearity, mixed-type-data

I have a dataset that has 17 variables. 9 categorical and 8 continuous. Some have more than 2 levels. I've reduced the dimensionality significantly. I am looking for strategies to test for colinearity within the dataset before I construct the logistic model and test for collinearity there.

I can just split the model into subsets of the categorical and continuous data then test fo collinearity there. Then do so again for the logistic model with an Anova test. But I am not sure what the best options might be.

Comment: 17 variables is a lot. What is your research question you are trying to address? You should really be able reduce the number of variables down to the ones that address your research question, and then worry about collinearity. EDIT: You should also explain what field you are using the logistic model for. For example, if you are researching econometrics, many variables are sometimes used. Epidemiology, not as much.

Comment: What is your interest in finding collinearity?

Comment: This is for econometrics evaluating loan default risk. The idea is to make a predictive model that can better determine loan default. The logistic model being 16 variables to the target variable of Defaull. Which is binary categorical. This is over 60 years of loan records and several million rows.

Comment: So what is your interest in finding collinearity?

Comment: To see if the predictors have collinearity as I build out the logistic model.

Comment: Yes, your interest is in finding collinearity between the predictors...why?

Comment: Is this some kind of rhetorical question?

Comment: Your reason for being interested in collinearity will influence how you address the potential collinearity. Please say why you’re interested in finding collinearity. As one of our new mods likes to say, please edit this information into the original post, as not everyone reads comments.

Comment: Because collinearity between the predictors will negatively affect the logistic model as the predictors need to be sufficiently independent of one another.

Comment: Depending on your reason for fitting the model, that is incorrect. Correlated predictors inflates the standard errors of parameter estimates, but that isn’t an issue for the predictive modeling you seem to want to do. If you have further questions about this, please post a new question.